# cumulative sums

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of integers.  The first `n` members of the lists will, when added to each other, will result in the `n + 1` st member of the list. .  I would like to replace each list with the accumulated sum when a match occurs; if there is more than one match (e.g. `lis5`), replace the list with the numerically largest match.

```
lis1 = {8,2,3,9,22} res1 = 22

lis2 = {9,11,21,3,44,12,3} res2 = 44

lis3 = {3,8,2,1,12,26} res3 = 26

lis4 = {8,4,6,2,9,11,40,3} res4 = 40

lis5 = {3,7,10,2,14,36,4} res5 = 36 (not 10)
```

Testing recursively the accumulated sum against each succeeding element until a match is found.  Thanks for any ideas...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This function should do:

```
f = x \[Function] Last[Intersection[x, Accumulate[x]]]
```

(Note that `Intersection` automatically orders lists, so we merely have to take the last element of the intersection.)

Testing:

```
lists = {{8, 2, 3, 9, 22},
   {9, 11, 21, 3, 44, 12, 3},
   {3, 8, 2, 1, 12, 26},
   {8, 4, 6, 2, 9, 11, 40, 3},
   {3, 7, 10, 2, 14, 36, 4}
   };
f /@ lists
```

> {22, 44, 26, 40, 36}

**Edit**

kglr pointed out that the equality of position might be necessary for a match. In this case, the following function might be what you are looking for.

```
g = x \[Function] Max[Pick[Rest[x], Unitize[Accumulate[Most[x]] - Rest[x]], 0]]
```

We obtain

```
g /@ lists
```

> {22, 44, 26, 40, 36}

and with kglr's `lists2`

```
lists2 = {{22, 2, 9, 8, 3},
   {9, 3, 12, 44, 3, 21, 11},
   {12, 8, 2, 3, 1, 26},
   {2, 11, 6, 8, 4, 9, 3, 40},
   {3, 10, 4, 7, 14, 36, 2}
   };
g /@ lists2
```

> {-∞, 12, 26, -∞, -∞}

(And yes, the supremum of an empty set is $-\infty$.)

Comment: Henrik, `Intersection[x, Accumulate[x]]` does not guarantee the requirement that positions match.

Comment: @kglr Good point! Maybe edit resolves that...

Comment: Since I like syntactic brevity: `f = Last[# ⋂ Accumulate[#]] &`

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to recognize that what you want is the max value in each list. Hence:

```
lists = {{8, 2, 3, 9, 22}, 
         {9, 11, 21, 3, 44, 12, 3}, 
         {3, 8, 2, 1, 12, 26}, 
         {8, 4, 6, 2, 9, 11, 40, 3}, 
         {3, 7, 10, 2, 14, 36, 4}};
 Max @@@ lists
{22, 44, 26, 40, 36}
```

Comment: I should have made the question more general: the last element in the list could be a higher number than the preceding, e.g. lis6 = {3,7,10,17,37,40} which requires Henrik's solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
f1 = Module[{i = Length@#, a = #, b = Accumulate @ #}, 
    While[a[[i]] - b[[--i]] != 0 && i > 0]; ; If[i == 0, {}, a[[i + 1]]]] &;
f2 = Module[{a = Reverse @ Accumulate @ Most @ #, b = Reverse @ Rest @ #, l}, 
    l = LengthWhile[a - b, # != 0 &]; If[l == Length@a, {}, a[[1 + l]]]] &;
```

Examples:

```
lists = {{8, 2, 3, 9, 22},
   {9, 11, 21, 3, 44, 12, 3},
   {3, 8, 2, 1, 12, 26},
   {8, 4, 6, 2, 9, 11, 40, 3},
   {3, 7, 10, 2, 14, 36, 4}};

{f1 /@ lists, f2 /@ lists}
```

> {{22, 44, 26, 40, 36}, {22, 44, 26, 40, 36}}

```
SeedRandom[1]
lists2 = RandomSample/@lists
```

> {{22, 2, 9, 8, 3},
>    {9, 3, 12, 44, 3, 21, 11},
>    {12, 8, 2, 3, 1,  26},
>   {2, 11, 6, 8, 4, 9, 3, 40},
>    {3, 10, 4, 7, 14, 36, 2}}

```
{f1 /@ lists2, f2 /@ lists2}
```

> {{{}, 12, 26, {}, {}}, {{}, 12, 26, {}, {}}}

Answer (score 4):

```
(Pick[#, (#1 - #2) & @@@ FoldList[{#2, Total@Flatten@{#1}} &, #],0][[-1]]) & /@ lists
```

> {22, 44, 26, 40, 36}

**Original Answer**

'Borrowing' from [bill s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174161/106)

```
Max@Cases[FoldList[{#2, Total@Flatten@{#1}} &, lst5], {x_, x_} :> x]
```

> 36

```
lists = {{8, 2, 3, 9, 22}, {9, 11, 21, 3, 44, 12, 3}, {3, 8, 2, 1, 12,
 26}, {8, 4, 6, 2, 9, 11, 40, 3}, {3, 7, 10, 2, 14, 36, 4}};

Max@Cases[FoldList[{#2, Total@Flatten@{#1}} &, #], {x_, x_} :> x] & /@ lists
```

> {22, 44, 26, 40, 36}

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thank you for that nice edit!